# Callback inside a Module

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have something similar to this:

```
Module A
    Class A
        def initialize
        end

        def m1
        end

        def m2
        end

        def m3
        end
    end
end
```

What I want is to run a validation before m1, m2, or m3 is executed, like a before_action, to return nil if is a condition is satisfied, for instance, if a variable is nil, return nil immediately.

I know that I can create a module:

```
module Callbacks
  def callbacks
    @callbacks ||= Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
  end

  def before_run(method_name, callback)
    callbacks[method_name] << callback
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def run_callbacks_for(method_name)
      self.class.callbacks[method_name].to_a.each do |callback|
        send(callback)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And inside the Class A, I can call:

```
before_run :m1, :my_validation_method
before_run :m2, :my_validation_method
before_run :m3, :my_validation_method
```

Is there any other clean way of doing this?

Comment: If you are using Rails 3 as indicated by the tags you can use ActiveModel::Callbacks or ActiveModel::Validations instead of reinventing the wheel. See https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/

Comment: Should I use ActiveModel even if I am not working with any model/database?

Comment: ActiveModel can really be mixed into any class to give it model like behavior. If you want a more generalized implementation of callbacks you can use ActiveSupport::Callbacks which is the basis for both model and controller callbacks.

Comment: @anothermh Yes, you are right. I just updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure, but I guess you can use `prepend`
For example:

```
module Baz
  def foo
    return nil if @a == 0
    super
  end
end

class Foo
  prepend Baz
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def foo
    p 'foo'
  end
end
```

User like

```
Foo.new(0).foo
=> nil

Foo.new(1).foo
"foo"
=> "foo"
```

Comment: I like this example. The is problem is that I will duplicate many lines. Imagine that I have 10 methods. Is there a way to avoid writing the same code 10 times?